# Can I pass a block which itself expect a block to instance_exec in ruby？

Tags: ruby, block, proc

I expect the code

```
foo=proc{puts "foo"}

instance_exec(1,2,3,&foo) do |*args , &block|
  puts *args
  block.call
  puts "bar"
end
```

to   output

```
1
2
3
foo
bar
```

But got the error

```
both block arg and actual block given
```

Can I pass a block which itself expect a block to instance_exec in ruby？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&foo` tries to pass `foo` as a block to `instance_exec`, and you are already passing an explicit block. Omitting ampersand sends `foo` just like any other argument (except that it is a `Proc` instance). So, try this instead:

```
instance_exec(1,2,3,foo) do |*args, block|
  puts *args
  block.call
  puts "bar"
end
```

This also means that you can do something like:

```
bar = proc{ |*args, block|
  puts *args
  block.call
  puts "bar"
}

instance_exec(1,2,3,foo,&bar)
```

And get the same result.

More info at [Difference between block and &block in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386276/difference-between-block-and-block-in-ruby)

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for my case. I'm trying to transparently wrap an existing proc in a way that allows me to track its execution time. Since I have no control over the signature of the proc I'm wrapping, I can't use this method. In general though this seems like a good work-around.

Answer (score 3):

I'm about 3 years late to this party, but I thought I'd share an approach that let's you treat the inner block more like a real block, rather than just a plain old argument.

The best way I know of to go about this is to create an object to act as a binding context and define the outer block as a method. So if I rewrite the original example as follows without the instance_exec call...

```
inner_proc = proc { puts "inner" }
outer_proc = proc { |*args, &inner_block|
  puts *args
  inner_block.call
  puts "bar"
}
```

We can define `outer_proc` as a method on an object

```
scope_object = Object.new
scope_object.define_singleton_method :bound_proc, &outer_proc
```

Now you can call `scope_object.bound_proc` instead of the `instance_exec` call above.

```
scope_object.bound_proc 1, 2, 3, &inner_proc
```

You'll get:

```
1
2
3
inner
bar
```

Unfortunately, you'll get a LocalJumpError if you try to yield inside of `outer_proc`, rather than the `inner_block.call`, I'm not entirely sure why. If someone has that answer then I'd be interested.